# css div id container fails to show background image for percent height and width

Tags: css, html

Why does the CSS div id gamecontainer not show the background image if height and width are in percent? It works in pixels, but I want it to fill different screen sizes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#gamecontainer {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg");
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.gamelayer {
    width:640px;
    height:480px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gamecontainer">
<canvas id="gamecanvas" width="100%" height="100%" class="gamelayer">           
</canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using vw or vh instead of percentage. It is bases the size relative to 1% of the screen size. For example

Instead of

```
body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
```

Try

```
body {
 height:100vh;
 width:100vw;
}
```

Here is an example of how it's used

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_vw

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this, then about the question why, i cant answer that, i am not good in explanation, just add `width` and `height` to your `html`.

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#gamecontainer {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg");
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.gamelayer {
    width:640px;
    height:480px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="gamecontainer">
<canvas id="gamecanvas" width="100%" height="100%" class="gamelayer">        
</canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `html` with 100% width and height beside the `body` so it should be like this:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```